# Leave iPhone on when changing SIM card

Tags: iphone, sim

I have to switch quite often between 2 SIM cards on my iPhone. I always used to turn it off to do that, however, it seems to work just fine even if I leave it on. Can it harm my iPhone or SIM card or the data on in any way by not turning it off during the procedure?

Comment: What version of iPhone? Dual sim adapters do exist for most of them.

Comment: It is an iPhone4s. I've heard about dual adapters, but the whole SIM card swapping is just a temporary thing...

Comment: Note that removing the SIM CARD can result in [LOSS OF YOUR VISUAL VOICEMAIL MESSAGES](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201337). Note you can [RECOVER YOUR VOICEMAIL FROM AN ICLOUD BACKUP](https://www.tenorshare.com/guide/how-to-restore-data-from-icloud-backup.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not harm your device or SIM card. Although Apple mentions it in [their manual](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2309) and theoretically you can short-circuit your device (I have no clue how, but theoretically...), in practice, when done with common sense, this should not harm your device. You do need to be careful with static charges and dust.

Comment: Thank you. Theoretical things tend to happen from time to time so I'll probably stick with the save way.

Comment: The linked help page used to say [*"When changing the SIM card, power off the device before opening the SIM tray"*](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301090234/http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2309), but not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When I went to Italy back in March I purchased a SIM card upon arrival as the cost per minute was a little less expensive than my home network.  The agent popped the card right out and put a new one in all while the phone was powered on and there was no problem at all.  Even so I'm more comfortable powering it off to replace the SIM card and did that when I got back to the US.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't take this as a reference. And as I stated in my question, I know it works, I was asking if it might do any harm on hardware or data. But thanks for sharing the experience.